# Blank page Ionic 4 android 5.1

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk, ionic4

I have an issue ,

I had develop an **Ionic 4** app and doesn't  make it run on `Adroid 5.1`

Here is the info:

```
Ionic:   
ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.2.1
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.7.5
@angular/cli                  : 6.1.5
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : not installed

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1, browser 5.0.4
Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin- 
ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 7 other plugins)

System:

NodeJS : v11.0.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm    : 6.4.1
OS     : Windows 10
```

I have installed crosswalk in case this is a issue with the Ionic-webView.
(cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview)

Here is the config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^1.4.5">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="27.+" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="2.4.0">
    <variable name="XWALK_VERSION" value="23+" />
    <variable name="XWALK_LITEVERSION" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
    <variable name="XWALK_COMMANDLINE" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
    <variable name="XWALK_MODE" value="embedded" />
    <variable name="XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK" value="true" />
</plugin>
<engine name="android" spec="^5.1.1" />
<engine name="browser" spec="5.0.4" />
```

On emulated devices of 7.1+ works fine.

The chrome developer tools says:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode. (I have installed
>   the last version of nodejs)

I appreciate any ideas.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

This is a know issue in ionic 4. Check this [link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15438). 
Best regard!

Answer (score 0):

Add/Uncomment in projectRoot/src/Polyfill.ts

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```